# webapp2 routing returns 404

Tags: python, google-app-engine, webapp2

I am trying to use webapp2 routing and this is currently failing. It does not seem to match the routing rules I set up and as a result returns a 404 for certain rules.

My code is like:

main.py

```
    import webapp2, urls

    app = webapp2.WSGIApplication(urls.SITE_URL_PATTERNS, debug=True)
```

urls.py

```
    from webapp2 import Route
    from webapp2_extras import routes

    import test_handler


    SITE_URL_PATTERNS = [
            routes.PathPrefixRoute('/admin', [
                    Route(r'/action_one', test_handler.take_action_one),
                    Route(r'/action_two', test_handler.take_action_two),
                    Route(r'/<action_three:\w+>', test_handler.take_action_three),
            ]),
            Route(r'/view/action_one', test_handler.view_action_one),
            Route(r'/', test_handler.view_homepage),
    ]
```

app.yaml

```
    - url: .*
        script: main.app
```

I can not seem to load /view/action_one (returns a 404), but I can load /admin/action_one.

Any suggestions on what I am doing wrong here? Appreciate your help!

Comment: What does the rest of your app.yaml file have in it (I assume python27, for if not the whole thing wouldn't work)? Have you tried placing `Route('r/view/action_one'...` before the `PathPrefixRoute` in `SITE_URL_PATTERNS`?

Comment: Thanks for helping me here! The rest of app.yaml has the standard stuff, including the python27 reference. I did  try to move the `Route('r/view/action_one'...` before the `PathPrefixRoute` and even outside (by having two lists and doing += on the lists. None of it worked. I am really confused why this is not working.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I found my stupid error (yes, a real "DOH!" moment):

```
Route(r'/<action_three:\w+>'
```

Should be

```
Route(r'/<action_three:[^/]+>'
```

It had problems matching the datastore keys as these can include other characters that are represented by \w. Going for everything else but / will normally solve this problem (use [^/]+).

Hope this will help someone else as well.